# Append jQuery adds HTML to next table cell with position absolute

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm appending a span element with jQuery to a table divider (although this questions is more css/html).

Since I started using position absolute (which I need for my width attribute), it now appends to the next table divider along to the one that I want.

See below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var var1 = 2
  var element = $('td').filter(function() {
    var holidayText = $(this).contents()[0].textContent.trim();
    return parseInt(holidayText, 10) == var1;
  });
  var cell_width = element.width();

  var2 = 3;
  var width = var2 * cell_width;

  add_html = element.append('</br><span class="spanclass" style="width: ' + width + 'px; position: absolute"></span>');
});
```

```css
div.class1 {
  position: relative;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid navy;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

table td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6ec;
}

span.spanclass {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I thought that append put it inside the element... so I'm a little confused?

How do I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `td`'s need `position: relative;`, which will mean the `span` is positioned relative to the `td`, then the `span`s need `top` and `left` value to position them in the `td`

```css
div.class1 {
 position: relative;
}
table {
 border:1px solid navy;
 width: 70%;
 text-align: center;
}
table th {
 text-align: center;
 width:100px;
 height:20px;
}
table td {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 vertical-align: top;
 text-align: right;
 border: 1px solid #c6c6ec;
    position: relative;
}
span.spanclass {
 background-color: purple;
 height: 14px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 2px;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var var1 = 2
  var element = $('td').filter(function() { 
    var holidayText = $(this).contents()[0].textContent.trim();
    return parseInt(holidayText, 10) == var1;
  });
  var cell_width = element.width();

  var2 = 3;
  var width =  var2*cell_width;
  
  add_html = element.append('</br><span class="spanclass" style="width: '+width+'px; position: absolute"></span>');

});
</script>
```

Comment: Ah this works pretty well but now I've added position relative, it appends just fine in the first cell, then in the rest the span appears **behind** the table cells in my own code... any ideas?

Comment: Ah sorted it with z-index:1000;
Thanks!

Comment: @RuthYoung yep z-index is all you need, though fwiw, it just needs to be non-zero, so `z-index: 1` works without having to create a crazy high number. People love to put crazy high numbers in z-index for some reason :) Updated my answer.